# How to appear two times in the django template?

Tags: django, templates, compare, timespan

I have two times: **{{maine.job_time}}** and **{{maine.transport_time}}**, I can add them using {% load mathfilters%}. That works well.
I want to check now if the result of {{aine.job_time | add: maine.transport_time}} is equal to "3:00:00" displays OK. But my condition does not work.
Can you help me solve this problem?
Thank you
Here is my Django template:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load mathfilters %}

{% block content %}
    {% if semain %}
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> {{ dim }} </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {% for maine in SemaineView %}
                            {% if  maine.date|date:"D" == "dim" %}
                              <p class='postcontent' ><strong>job:</strong> {{ maine.job_time}}</p>
                              <p class='postcontent' ><strong>transport:</strong> {{ maine.transport_time }}</p>
                              <p class='postcontent' ><strong>Total:</strong> {{ maine.job_time|add:maine.transport_time }}</p>

                              {% if  maine.job_time|add:maine.transport_time== "3:00:00" %}
                                <h1> ok </h1>
                              {% else %}
                                <h1> Non </h1>
                              {% endif %}

                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {{ tr }}
                    </td>                       
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You use this lib https://github.com/dbrgn/django-mathfilters_?

Comment: Yes I used lib: https://github.com/dbrgn/django-mathfilters. The calculation works well. But I can not seem to compare two results. Like                                {% if  maine.job_time|add:maine.transport_time== "3:00:00" %}
                                <h1> ok </h1>
                              {% else %}
                                <h1> Non </h1>
                              {% endif %}

Comment: the addition works fine? you tested?

Comment: Yes addition works fine and I tested.

Comment: if you job_time and transport time are datatime, you must format the output of addition. you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#time 
for this.

Comment: finally, I made the comparison in my view by returning the result in a context. And in my templete, I recover the context:
tel = heure.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id).aggregate(Sum('nbr_heure')).get('nbr_heure__sum', 00.00)
if tel < datetime.timedelta(hours=8,minutes=00, seconds=00):
    context['job_0'] = tel
if tel == datetime.timedelta(hours=8,minutes=00, seconds=00):
   context['job_1'] = tel
context['tr'] = tel